# How do I get the path to a DMG (disk image) file given the mounted volume path?

Tags: macos, filesystem, metadata

I tried `hdiutil info -plist`, but if I shift the DMG file elsewhere after mounting it, it doesn't update the DMG path. If I right click and select 'Get info' on the volume, I'm able to view the correct DMG path.

Comment: Hi jaume. I tried this on MacOS 10.12.6 desktop. Did you try it on a laptop? Not sure if that's the reason or the DMG itself. But yes, if I'm shifting it, the path in Get info changes.

Answer (score 5):

A somewhat pedestrian way would be to retrieve the name of your DMG file from the output of `hdiutil` and then search for it, e.g., via

```
hdiutil info -plist | grep dmg | sed 's/<string>\([^<]*\)<\/string>/\1/' | xargs basename | xargs mdfind -name
```

You may need to modify the `grep dmg` part to be smarter if you have several images mounted, or you loop through all DMG files reported by `hdiutil`, e.g.,

```
for F in `hdiutil info -plist | grep dmg | sed 's/<string>\([^<]*\)<\/string>/\1/'`
  do basename $F | xargs mdfind -name
done
```

However, none of the above takes your mount path as input. To do that, you could add a `sed` command in the pipe that extracts the paragraph of interest, e.g.,

```
hdiutil info -plist | tail -r | sed -n '/\/Volumes\/MOUNTNAME/,/dmg/p' | grep dmg | sed 's/<string>\([^<]*\)<\/string>/\1/' | xargs basename | xargs mdfind -name
```

Perhaps it is also easier to work on the direct output of `hdiutil info`, without the `-plist` flag.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestion. However if I have multiple DMGs of the SAME name, this would cause a problem right? I can modify grep to retrieve the DMG path where I originally mounted from, then I guess I can apply a check whether this DMG still exists in that path else look for it on the computer. But yeah problem being of the same name ones on different locations.

Comment: Try `hdiutil info -plist | tail -r | sed -n '/\/Volumes\/MOUNTNAME/,/dmg/p' | grep dmg | sed 's/<string>\([^<]*\)<\/string>/\1/' | xargs basename | xargs mdfind -name`, where you of course have to adapt `MOUNTNAME`...

Comment: Yes but same problem will arise :P If I've multiple DMGs on computer with same name, they will all be listed. I want the specific one related to Mount path.

Comment: Well, the `sed` that extracts the paragraph of your mount path takes care of that, unless all your mount points had the same path as well... that'd pose an interesting conundrum.

Comment: Take a situation, where I take abc.dmg and keep it in Downloads. Also I keep a copy in Desktop (same name) now I mount it from Downloads, so a Volume path gets created with Downloads abc.dmg. Now I run your command, it'll take abc.dmg and give me 2 locations : Downloads/abc.dmg and Desktop/abc.dmg
Get where I'm going?

Comment: Your solutions have problems with word splitting. All will fail if the diskimage filename has spaces in the name.

Comment: @fd0 hm, spaces in the file's name seem to work fine on my system. `hdiutil info -plist | tail -r | sed -n '/\/Volumes\/Flash\ Player/,/dmg/p' | grep dmg | sed 's/<string>\([^<]*\)<\/string>/\1/' | xargs basename | xargs mdfind -name` correctly returns
 `/Users/monomeric/Downloads/install flash player osx.dmg` after mounting the DMG

Comment: @ShrutiGupta if you have different files with different content at different locations but sharing the same base name, then I'd suggest that you keep track of them via checksums.

Comment: Well, either you have IFS set to newline or you are using `zsh`?  It fails in `bash` and `ksh`.

Comment: I'm not aware of the existence of other shells than `zsh` [^_^], and yes, my IFS is newline. Isn't that the default on macos?

Comment: Ok thanks @monomeric but I don't think I can compare checksums without knowing which dmg I'm looking for exactly :P Just want to clarify that there are no other existing commands which give updated DMG path given volume path right? Other than hdiutil?

Comment: There are ways to trace file system changes, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429270/macos-x-file-system-watcher, however, you would probably need to know the location of your initial DMG before moving it in any case.

Comment: Yes I can know the initial DMG path through hdiutil info -plist. It is the new location that I need in my code (in case the path is changed)

Answer (score 0):

macos 11.6.8

```
hdiutil info | grep image-path | sed 's/.*: //'
```

Comment: It's hardly ever necessary to `grep` before `sed` -> `hdiutil info | sed -n '/image-path/s/.*: //p'`. But the more general issue here is that it doesn't seem to solve the problem stated in the question. ("I tried hdiutil info -plist, but if I shift the DMG file elsewhere after mounting it, it doesn't update the DMG path")

Answer (score 0):

If you have something that can do XPath lookups (like `xq`), it's possible:

```sh
DMG_PATH=/path/to/file.dmg
hdiutil info -plist | xq -x "//dict/array/dict/key[text() = 'image-path']/following-sibling::string[1][text() = '$DMG_PATH']/../array/dict/key[text() = 'mount-point']/following-sibling::string[1]/text()"
```